# Obtaining UICollectionViewCell Label text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

My Current code for performing  the segue to my next view controller is as follows:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell IconImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    [[cell IconLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GroupsHomeSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"])
    {


        //IconImage is the name of the image in GroupsViewController i want to pass through. Based upon what each cell is set at anyways.

        //logoImage is the name of the image i want to set in GroupsHomeViewController.

        //so basically i want to be able to get IconImage and set it as logoImage in a different view controller

    }
}
```

The problem that i am having, is how do i obtain the value of my text from each selected cell individually so that i can post it as another label in a detailed view controller.

The comment lines within my prepare for segue describe exactly what i am trying to achieve. I simply want to obtain the value of an individual UICollectionViewCell Label.text

This may seem similar to previous passing data through view controller posts, but this is different to anything that i have found due to the fact that in these posts the text values are constant i.e the value of the label.text is set to one thing and are not coming from an array.

I would simply just like to know how to find the label value of an individually selected cell and pass it through to my detailed view controller.

[image: I Have updated the code following examples giving and still no result as the picture does not show.]

Comment: When you do perform segue with identifier, you can also send indexPath in sender and in prepare for segue, typecast the sender as indexPath and get the value.

Answer (score 1):

To pass information to the next view controller during a segue, you would use the `destinationViewController` property on the `segue` parameter passed to `prepareForSegue:sender:`.  You will have to setup properties on that destination view controller to be able to set the values, of course.

To determine what information the user selected, you have a few options.  You can create a property on your view controller to store what the user selected and put that value in the property during `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` based on the `indexPath` paramter, or you can use the `UICollectionView` method `indexPathsForSelectedItems` to get the index path of the selected items during `prepareForSegue:sender:`.  I tend to do the latter.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [[someCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] first];
        if(indexPath != nil)
        {
            NSString* selectedDescription = arrayOfDescriptions[indexPath.item];
            NSString* selectedImageName = arrayOfImages[indexPath.item];

            // Get the destination view controller (the one that will be shown) from the segue and cast it to the appropriate type.  Assuming this should be GroupsHomeViewController, but I'm not entirely sure that's correct since I can't see all your code
            GroupsHomeViewController* groupsHomeViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            // Set the appropriate properties (Again, I'm guessing here since I can't see your code)
            groupsHomeViewController.logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed: selectedImageName];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i get the individual Value of my Label within my uicollectionviewcell? is there some form of short code that i could use or will i have to use NSLog to obtain which cell i am clicking on? and then go from there to find the value of the exact cell

Comment: I'm not sure how you can use `NSLog()` in the way you're suggesting.  You can retrieve the cell from the collection view given you have the `indexPath` of the selected cell, and examine the cell's label (and other) properties.  Having said that, given that you populate the label from an array of values, you can also just grab the value from your array directly with the `indexPath` of the selected cell.  I've added a little code for your reference.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you're in Objective-C, I'll update the example code.

Comment: Sorry i didn't reply sooner my app notifications have been a little funny lately, where you have stated configure destination view controller? what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your help i have updated my original post with a screenshot of the errors that i am receiving when trying out your method just now, it includes some more of my code thanks again

Comment: So, the first error is you trying to use the class `UICollectionView` instead of an instance of it.  Based on your other code, it should be `self.GroupsCollectionView`.  The second error is because you're missing a `}` in the code I provided.  There's also a warning because `groupsHomeViewController.logoImage` is a `UIImageView` not a `UIImage`.  You'll probably want to setup a `UIImage` property on that view controller and set that instead, then set the the `image` property of `logoImage` in that view controller's `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: After following your instructions and removing all of the errors from my code, i can now run it, the only problem is that I'm not getting the picture in the next view controller? i have also updated my code in the post to show you what changes i have made to the code.

Comment: Hard for me to speculate, since I can't see the code.  You might consider formulating and asking a new question though, since this one is solved.  Have you put breakpoints in the destination view controller and inspected that values are passed as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

In "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" pass the indexPath as "sender" (Please see the below code). And in "performSegueWithIdentifier" you will get the indexPath of selected cell.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GroupsHomeSegue" sender:indexPath];
    }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"])
            {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;
                NSString* iconImage = arrayOfImages[indexPath.row];

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code-

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView        didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GroupsHomeSegue" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"])
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtindexPath:sender];
    NSString *text = cell.IconLabel.text;
    UIImage *image = cell.IconImage.image;
    GroupsHomeViewController* ghVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    groupsHomeViewController.logoImage = image;


}
}
```